# Is using for-statements in R considered bad style?

Tags: r, functional-programming

R is a functional programming language. Many for-statements can be replaced by one of the apply-functions. Thus, isn't the for-statement against the functional programming paradigm? Is using for-statements considered bad style, in the sense of functional programming?

Comment: This is a weird question, it all depends on your needs... for example I needed to know if my results were reliable, so I used a for-statement to run my program many times (different random number everytime) and I was able to conclude.
What do you need to do ?

Comment: What is your input and desired output? Is this a specific programming question or a philosophy question? Please provide example code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `for` loop is against the functional programming paradigm. However, R is not a pure functional programming language. It allows side effects.

There are scenarios where a `for` loop is appropriate. In particular, if you don't need a return value, but only a side effect such as plotting or exporting files, `for` loops are more appropriate than `*apply` functions.

Then there are some tasks that a just easier to solve with a `for` loop. E.g., if you look at the source of the `Reduce` function you'll find a `for` loop.